# Pasar variable PHP7 a jQuery

Tags: jquery, php7

Estoy realizando un módulo de cambio de contraseña. Quisiera que, con jQuery me tome el valor de un input por el método keyup y lo almacene en una variable; posteriormente esa variable jQuery se pase a una de PHP7 para hacer una consulta con respecto a lo que el usuario vaya ingresando.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
 $(document).keyup("#documento_cambio", function(e){
  var valor=$("#documento_cambio").val();
  <?php
  $v="<script>valor</script>";
  $consultar_usuario=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE documento_usuario='$v'");
  $contar=$consultar_usuario->num_rows;
  ?>
  var i=<?php echo $contar; ?>;
  if (valor!="") {
   if (i<=0) {
    $("#documento_cambio").css('border-color',"#F35B3F");
   }else{
    $("#documento_cambio").css('border-color',"#59B548");
   }
  }else{
   $("#documento_cambio").css('border-color',"#D3D3D3");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
#contenedor_cambio{
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 padding:2em;
 width:40%;
 left:28%;
 border-radius:30px;
}
#contenedor_cambio input{
 border:2px solid #D3D3D3;
 border-radius:20px;
 padding:1em;
 width:100%;
}
.error{
 border-color:#F35B3F;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_cambio">
 <form>
  <input type="number" name="documento_cambio" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de documento..." id="documento_cambio" class="error">
 </form>
 <?php
 echo $v;
 ?>
</div>
```

Este es el código que uso. La variable `$v` no recibe nada. Quisiera saber cómo pasar la variable jQuery a PHP7.

Comment: Investiga sobre Ajax.

Comment: Sé que AJAX envía datos por los diferentes métodos. Pero... ¿También sirve para enviar a la misma página?

Comment: Si sirve y no necesariamente lo tienes que hacer todo en la misma pagina.

Comment: Sí. Yo eso lo sé. Lo que por el momento necesito, es que me cambie el estilo del input con respecto a la consulta, como está en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

**La mejor forma de solucionar tu problema es:**
Crear una [Api en php](https://www.weblantropia.com/2016/08/30/restful-api-api-php-mysql/) y posteriormente enviar los datos a php con peticiones [Ajax/axios/fetch a php](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/03/12/axios-php-ejemplo-peticiones-ajax/).
Con el segundo enlace deberías poder crear todo lo que necesitas y poder enviar los datos a PHP sin ningún problema.

> Espero que te resultará útil